# Лишняя запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

— Он что, у вас(,) бессмертный?

Интонационно хочется выделить, но не знаю, есть ли правило.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С *что* возможны пунктуационные варианты в зависимости от значения.

Правильно: *Он что у вас, бессмертный?*

Здесь *что* выступает в роли сказуемого в значении *каков?*. Ср.: *Ну, что море, что небо? Какие краски там?* (Гонч.)

*Что же мне, стреляться из-за этой пропажи?* — неполное предложение со значением «что же мне делать?».

*Ты что же не идёшь с нами?* («почему»). — *Ты что же, не идёшь с нами?* («что делаешь?», пауза после что же).

Comment: Тат, вы хотите сказать, постановка запятой после что в данном примере невозможна? Он что, у вас бессмертный?

Comment: Так никто не скажет. Скажут "Он что у вас" или "Он у вас что", то есть "Он у вас какой?", а не "Он какой, у вас бессмертный?"

Answer (score 4):

Первая запятая не нужна, вторая нужна.

Comment: Вопросительно-восклицательные слова (частицы или их сочетания) что, что ли, ну как, что же, как же, ну, а, да ну, надо же выделяются запятыми внутри предложения или отделяются запятой, если стоят в начале предложения: — Сыночек, что, шибко он его зашиб-то? (Шукш.); — Что, хороша? — громко крикнула охрипшим голосом Маргарита Николаевна (Булг.); — Ну что ж, входите, раз звонили! — сказала девица (Булг.);
( Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина). http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=131#pp131

Answer (score 0):

Запятая, на мой взгляд, лишняя. А вот первая запятая поставлена верно: частица *что* имеет оттенок *подтверждения
информации* (могу ошибаться).

Нет, запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Вторая запятая не нужна.