# Нужна запятая? Сомнение 101

Tags: запятые

> Ты(,) что, уволился? Нужна запятая?

Comment: Сколько можно задавать одни те же вопросы!!  У матера Лео спросите.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427528/Он-что-тебе-не-поверил-Как-объяснить-запятую  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427528/Он-что-тебе-не-поверил-Как-объяснить-запятую   https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/37333/Лишняя-запятая

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Он что, тебе не поверил?" Как объяснить запятую?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427528/%d0%9e%d0%bd-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e)

Comment: ребрендинг не повлиял на качество задаваемых вопросов.